# How to get the row added by ajax in the right place?

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I have a table form created from a custom entity:

```
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $contract = NULL)
  {

    $form['subscriptions'] = [
      '#type'       => 'table',
    ];
    $form['subscriptions']['#header'] = [some stuff here];
//  here is the query to retrieve data from entity...  
    $results = db_query($query);
    foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
      $myKey = $key * 10;
      $form['subscriptions'][$myKey]['somefield'] = ['#markup' => $value->designation];
      $form['subscriptions'][$myKey]['anotherfield'] = [
        '#type'          => 'number',
        '#default_value' => $value->$sTemp,
      ];
      $form['subscriptions'][$myKey]['addRow'] = [
        '#type'  => 'submit',
        '#name'  => $myKey,
        '#value' => '+',
        '#ajax'  => [
          'callback' => '::ajaxAddRow',
          'wrapper'  => 'my_form_wrapper',
        ],
      ];
    }

    $form['#prefix'] = '<div id="my_form_wrapper">';
    $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';

    $form['submit'] = [
     '#type'  => 'submit',
     '#name'  => 'submit',
     '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
    ];
  return $form;
  }
```

The ajax callback:

```
  public function ajaxAddRow(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
  {
    $myKey = $form_state->getTriggeringElement()['#name'];
    $form['subscriptions'][$myKey + 5] = $form['subscriptions'][$myKey];
    return $form;
  }
```

The submitForm:

```
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
  {
    if ($form_state->getTriggeringElement()['#name'] == 'submit') {
        do some stuff then exit the form
    }
    else {
      $form_state->setRebuild();
    }
  }
```

When I click on '+' in some row, the form is displayed again with a copy of the row added to the table.
But the copy is added at the end of the table.
How can I have the copy added just after the original one?

Comment: Return the entire table instead off a single row. Replace the entire table. The sorting will happen on the server side.

Comment: I guess I already do that: `my_form_wrapper` is the whole form (I edited my question to add the way `my_form_wrapper` is defined) and I return `$form` in the ajax callback...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it work this way:

```
  public function ajaxAddRow(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
  {
    $myKey = $form_state->getTriggeringElement()['#name'];
    $formBis = [];
    foreach ($form as $key => $value) {
      switch ($key) {
        case 'subscriptions':
          foreach ($form['subscriptions'] as $key2 => $value2) {
            $formBis['subscriptions'][$key2] = $form['subscriptions'][$key2];
            if (is_numeric($key2)) {
              if ($key2 == $myKey) {           << Here is the row to be copied
                $keyfornewrow = $key2 + 5;
                $formBis['subscriptions'][$keyfornewrow] = $form['subscriptions'][$key2];
                foreach ($formBis['subscriptions'][$keyfornewrow] as $key3 => $value3) {
                    << some code here to initialize content of copied row >>
                }
              }
            }
          }
          break;
        default:
          $formBis[$key] = $form[$key];
      }
    }
    return $formBis;
  }
```